# If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $4ab-1 \mid 4a^2-1$ then $ a=b$.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $$(4ab-1) \mid (4a^2-1)$$ then $a=b$.

I am stuck with question, no idea. Is there any way to prove this using Polynomial Division Algorithm? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: This actually holds even with the weaker assumption that $ 4ab - 1 \mid (4a^2 - 1)^2 $.

Comment: I added a generalization to my answer which makes it crystal clear how this is nothing but the uniqueness of inverses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $4ab\equiv 1\pmod {4ab-1}$ and if $4ab-1\mid 4a^2-1$ then $4a^2\equiv 1\pmod{4ab-1}$. So $$b\equiv (4a^2)b=a(4ab) \equiv a\pmod{4ab-1}.$$

Is that possible if $a\neq b$?

Without using modular arithmetic, you can write this as:

$$a-b = b(4a^2-1)-a(4ab-1) $$

So $4ab-1\mid a-b$.

Comment: The proof is just a special case of the uniqueness of inverses - see my answer.

Comment: Well, yes, but you still arrive at $4ab-1\mid a-b$. @BillDubuque

Comment: The point is that viewing it this way makes everything obvious, even the requisite inequality (omitted in your answer). I expanded my remark to emphasize this - giving the natural generalization of the OP's theorem. Hopefully that makes my point clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Note $\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ 4ab\!-\!1\!:\,\ \overbrace{(4a)\color{#c00}a\equiv 1\equiv(4a)\color{#c00}b}^{\ \ \ \large \color{#c00}a\, \equiv\, (4a)^{-1}\equiv\,\color{#c00} b}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{a\equiv b}\ $ by **uniqueness of inverses** (of $\,4a\,$ here)

---

**Remark** $\ $ For completeness, here is the [standard proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033516/242) of *uniqueness* of inverses:

$$\ ca\equiv 1\equiv cb \,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv a(cb)\equiv (ac)b\equiv b\quad\ \ $$

The OP Theorem becomes obvious when expressed in this general form, amounting simply to the uniqueness of inverses mod $\,n\,$ *within the standard rep system* $\,\{0,1,\ldots,n\!-\!1\},\,$ namely

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\, \color{#0a0}{a< bc}\, $ and $\, bc\!-\!1\mid ac\!-\!1\ $ then $\ a = b,\ $ for integers $\,a,b,c > 0$

**Proof** $\ \ {\rm mod}\,\ n\!=\!bc\!-\!1\!:\,\ bc\equiv 1\equiv ac\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv c^{-1}\!\equiv b.\ $ $\,bc\!-\!1\mid ac\!-\!1\,\Rightarrow\,  b\le a \le \color{#0a0}{bc\!-\!2}\,$ (by $\,b\not\equiv 0).\,$ So $\,a\equiv b\pmod{n}\,$ and $\,a,b\in \{0,1,\ldots,\color{#0a0}{n\!-\!1}\}\Rightarrow\, a=b\,$ (else $\,n\,$ divides the smaller natural $\,a\!-\!b> 0,\,$ contradiction). $\ \ $ **QED**

The OP is the special case $\ c = 4a,\ $ where $\ a < 4ab = bc,\,$ so the Theorem applies.

Note how translating the theorem into the language of congruences has simplified it so much that we immediately recognize it as a special case of a well-known result about uniqueness of inverses. This is yet another example of a ubiquitous principle that I [frequently emphasize here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+uniqueness+powerful+) namely **uniqueness theorems provide powerful tools for proving equalities**.

Comment: I can understand this ` divides the smaller natural −>0, contradiction`. Contradiction with what? Can't find contradicting statement

Comment: @Joe $\ n\mid m\Rightarrow m\ge n\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $a \geq b$, since we need $4a^2-1 \geq 4ab-1$. We have
$$\dfrac{4a^2-1}{4ab-1} = k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Hence,
$$k = \dfrac{4a^2-1}{4ab-1} = \dfrac{4a^2-4ab+4ab-1}{4ab-1} = 1 + \dfrac{4b(a-b)}{4ab-1}$$
Now note that $\gcd(4ab-1,4b)=1$, since $(4b)a - (4ab-1) = 1$. Hence, $4ab-1$ divides $a-b$. However $0 \leq a-b < 4ab-1$. Hence, $a-b=0 \implies a=b$.

Comment: Have two doubts: #1: $\frac{4a^2 -4ab+4ab-1}{4ab-1} = \frac{4a(a-b) +4ab-1}{4ab-1}= \frac{4a(a-b)}{4ab-1} +1$. Am not clear how this leads to : $\frac{4b(a-b)}{4ab-1}+1$? #2: But, the error (as per me) doesn't matter as need show just that $\gcd(4ab-1, 4a)= 1$, since $(4a)b - (4ab-1)= 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that any  integer
$m \ge 2$
will do,
instead of 4.

For example,
take Thomas Andrew's solution,
and put $m$ for $4$ everywhere:

Note that $mab\equiv 1\pmod {mab-1}$
 and if $mab-1\mid ma^2-1$ 
then $ma^2\equiv 1\pmod{mab-1}$. 
So $$b\equiv (ma^2)b=a(mab) \equiv a\pmod{mab-1}.$$

Is that possible if $a\neq b$?

Without using modular arithmetic, you can write this as:

$$a-b = b(ma^2-1)-a(mab-1) $$

So $mab-1\mid a-b$.

My note:

To show that
$mab-1 > a-b$ for $m \ge 2$,
$ab-a+b-1
=(a+1)(b-1)
\ge 0
$.

Note that
if $m=b=1$,
then
$mab-1 = a-1$.

Comment: Yes: $\ (ma)a\equiv 1\equiv (ma)b\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv (ma)^{-1}\equiv b\,$ by *uniqueness* of inverses, see my answer. To get the general result replace $\,ma\,$ by $\,c\,$ above.

Comment: Update: even the inequality has a natural interpretation when viewed from this standpoint: it is simply what's needed for the inverses to lie in the standard rep range. So the theorem is *precisely* equivalent to the uniqueness of inverses in the standard rep range, except the congruence language has been removed, being replaced by equivalent divisibility language, which obscures the essence of the matter: inverse unqueness  (and it is further obfuscated by choice of a specific modulus). See the edit to my remark.for details.