# Why is $a^{-1}$ mod $p$ equal to $a^{p-2}$ mod $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Why is $a^{-1}$ mod $p$ equal to $a^{p-2}$ mod $p$ in modular arithmetic?

Comment: Because, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), if $a\neq 0\pmod{p}$, then $a^{p-1}=1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: How do you get from $a^{p-1} = 1$ to $a^{p-2} = a^{-1}$? Dividing both sides by $a$?

Comment: $a^{-1}\pmod{p}$ is defined to be the one (if existing) and only element in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ such that $$a^{-1}\cdot a=a\cdot a^{-1}=1\pmod{p}$$ and $a^{p-2}\pmod{p}$ satisfies this property whenever $a\neq 0\pmod{p}$. It is a general fact that uniqueness in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ follows from existence.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Are you saying the inverse of each number from $1$ to $p-1$ is different, modulo $p$?

Comment: $0$ does not have an inverse $\pmod{p}$. It is true that $x^{-1}=y^{-1}\pmod{p}\implies x=y\pmod{p}$, but what I said actually was that for all $a\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ it holds $$\begin{cases}b\cdot a=a\cdot b=1\pmod{p}\\c\cdot a=a\cdot c=1\pmod{p}\end{cases}\implies c=b\pmod{p}$$

Comment: I don't understand what that means or how it applies here. What is b and c and how is that relevant?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because $a^{p-1} = 1$ mod p in modular arithmetic, whenever p is a prime and a ≠ 0.

Answer (score 2):

${\rm mod}\ p\!:\ a\not\equiv 0\,\overset{\rm Fermat}\Longrightarrow\ \overbrace{a\, \color{#c00}{a^{p-2}}}^{\Large a^{p-1}}\equiv 1\ $ so $\ a^{-1}\equiv \color{#c00}{a^{p-2}}\ $ (by *definition* of "inverse")

Note: this implicitly uses [uniqueness of inverses](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033516/242). Proof: $ $ if $\, c',c\,$ are both inverses of $\, a\,$ then

$$  c' \equiv c'(ac)\equiv (c'a)c\equiv c\qquad $$

Such uniqueness holds very generally since the proof uses only *commutativity and associativity*.

**Remark** $\ $ Note that the proof uses [basic congruence laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337791/242), e.g. the first congruence multiplies  $\,\color{#c00}{1\equiv ac}\,$ times $\,c'\equiv c\,$ to get $\,c'\cdot\color{#c00}1\equiv c'(\color{#c00}{ac})\,$ by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337791/242).

The uniqueness of inverses (and uniqueness theorems in general) often play key roles in much less trivial ways. A nice recent example is [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1236370/242)  that $\,4ab-1 \mid 4a^2-1\,\Rightarrow\, a=b$.

Comment: What exactly is "unique" here? The inverse mod $p$? Are you saying the inverse of each number from $0$ to $p-1$ have unique inverses mod $p$?

Comment: @user64283 Here uniqueness means $\,ac\equiv 1\equiv ac'\,\Rightarrow\, c\equiv c'\pmod p,\ $ i.e. if $\,c\,$ and $\,c'$ are both inverses of $\,a\,$ then they are congruent.

Comment: i.e.  a root of the $\rm\color{#c00}{congruence}\,$ $\,ax\equiv 1\,$ is unique (up to congruence), i.e. $\color{#0a0}{\text{any two roots are }}\color{#c00}{\rm congruent}$.  It proves helpful to think of congruences as *generalized* $\rm\color{#90f}{equalities}$, recalling for equalities that an $\rm\color{#90f}{equation}$ has unique roots means $\color{#0a0}{\text{any two roots are }}\color{#90f}{\rm equal}$