# divisibility problem and gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let a and b be a positive integers. Proof that if number $ 100ab -1 $ divides number $ (100a^2 -1)^2 $ then also divides number $ (100b^2 -1)^2 $.

My attempt:

Let's notice that \begin{split} b^2(100a^2-1)^2 -a^2(100b^2-1)^2 & =(100a^2b-b)^2-(100ab^2-a)^2\\
 & =(100a^2b-b-100ab^2+a)(100a^2b-b+100ab^2-a)\\
 & =(100ab(a-b)+(a-b))(100ab(a+b)-(a+b))\\
 & =(a-b)(100ab+1)(a+b)(100ab-1).\end{split}

This means that $ 100ab-1 |a^2(100b^2-1)^2$, so if we proof that $\gcd(100ab-1,a^2)=1$ the proof is completed. Now I know that it  should be trivial to show that these numbers are relatively prime but somehow i have no idea how to do it.

Also I am intrested if there is a way to solve this problem by using modular arithmetic?

Comment: If $d>1$ is a prime factor of $a^2$ then $d|a$ and $d|100ab$ so $d\not | 100ab-1$ (it is one less than a multiple of $d$). So the terms have no prime factors in common and $\gcd(100ab-1,a^2)=1$.

Comment: Thank You! I get it now :)

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to interpret your proof modularly in a very simple way.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank You! You people are awesome!

Answer (score 3):

For a modular arithmetic argument:

Let $N=100ab-1$ and work modulo $N$.

Starting with $(100a^2 -1)^2\equiv 0$,  multiply by $10^4b^4$:
$$(10^4a^2b^2-100b^2)^2\equiv 0.$$

Since $10^2ab\equiv 1$, we have $(1-100b^2)^2\equiv 0.$

Comment: Could you explain last line a bit more? I get that $10^2ab \equiv 1$ by why these means that $(1-100b^2)^2\equiv 0$. I am sorry if this is a stupid question by I am just starting to learn some basic number theory.

Comment: In the previous line I have replaced $10^4a^2b^2=(100ab)^2$ by $1$.

Comment: I think i get. So let's say that $(x-y)^2\equiv 0 $ (mod n)and we know that $x\equiv 1 $then we can write that $(1-y)^2\equiv 0$?

Comment: Yes that's right. Modular arithmetic arguments are so easy!

Comment: Thank you! I have only one question. What properties of modular arithmetic we are using when we replace x by 1. I mean it obvious for me that if $x\equiv 1$ then $x-y \equiv1-y$ but why this is also true when we have $(x-y)^2$? Is it because we can multiply congruence's?

Comment: Since $x\equiv 1$, we have $x-y =1+kn-y$ for some $k$. When this is squared we can ignore all multiples of $N$ if we are working modulo $N$.

Comment: When carrying out such  a modular arithmetic argument just treat $x$ and $1$ as the same.

Comment: Okay. Thank You once again!

Comment: @S.Dolan Careful. It's not always the case, when dealing with modular arithmetic, that a number $x$ can be replaced by any other number $y$ congruent with $x$.

Comment: It is always the case for the elements of the ring of integers mod N involved in the arithmetical operations. It is not, of course, the case for  other elements such as those used in the standard notation for powers.

Comment: @Alice211 $\,x\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\,f(x)\equiv f(a)\,$ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with *integer* coef's - see the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) and other basic congruence arithmetic laws proved there. I added an answer which gives a more motivated derivation using modular arithmetic, which shows how it is a special case of a more general well-known method.

Answer (score 2):

We show how modular arithmetic allows us to view it as a special case of polynomial **reversal**, i.e. that $f(a)=0\Rightarrow \tilde f(a^{-1})=0,\,$ where $\tilde f$ denotes the reverse (reciprocol) polynomial.

Here mod arithmetic works nicely:  $\bmod 100ab-1\,$ we have $\,100ab\equiv 1\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{a \equiv 1/(100b)}.\,$ We can substitute this into any polynomial equation $\,f(\color{#c00}a)\equiv 0\,$ then clear denom's to get an equation $\,g(b)\equiv 0\,$ for $\,b.\,$ Here $f(a)\equiv (100\color{#c00}a^2-1)^2\equiv0\,$ so making said $\rm\color{#c00}{substitution}$ for $\,\color{#c00}a\,$ yields

$$0\equiv f(a) \equiv \left[\dfrac{100}{(\color{#c00}{100b})^2}-1\right]^2 \equiv \left[\dfrac{1-100b^2}{\color{#0a0}{100b^2}}\right]^2\!\Rightarrow (1-100b^2)^2\equiv 0\!\!$$

---

Your proof, viewed modularly, essentially *squares* the following equation (compare [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1236370/242))

$$\begin{align} 
b(\color{#c00}{100a}a-1) &\,\equiv\, a(1-\color{#0a0}{100b}b)\\
\iff\ \ b\ (\color{#c00}{b^{-1}}\ a-1) &\,\equiv\, a(1-\ \color{#0a0}{a^{-1}}\ b),\,\ \text{is true by both} \equiv a-b 
\end{align}\qquad$$

So squaring we get $\,(100aa-1)^2\equiv 0\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}{a^2}(1-100bb)^2\equiv 0\Rightarrow (1-100bb)^2\equiv 0\,$ by twice cancelling the unit (invertible) $\,\color{#0a0}a\,$, i.e. by scaling by $\,\color{#0a0}{a^{-1}\, (\equiv 100b)}$.

---

**Remark** $ $ We can do all arithmetic *fraction-free* by scaling $\,f(a)\,$ by $\,(\color{#0a0}{100b^2})^2$ (this is essentially what is done in S. Dolan's answer, but there the key idea $\rm\color{#c00}{(elimination)}$ is not brought to the fore).

Above is a slight variation of the following well known result: $ $ if  $\,a\,$ is a root of a polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ then $\,a^{-1}\,$ is a root of the [reciprocal (reverse) polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3830244/242) $\,x^{d}f(1/x),\,$ $\, d := \deg f,\,$ as above.

Thus by using modular arithmetic we can express the problem using *equations* (congruences) and this allows us to use well-known facts on the relationship between an equation for $\,a\,$ and one for its inverse $\,a^{-1}.\,$ This relationship would be obfuscated if we used only divisibility language (vs. congruence *equations*).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1236370/242) for a *linear* analog - which can be viewed as *uniqueness of inverses*.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4417381/242) for reciprocal / reverse divisibility tests.